# MS Access graph making capabilities

Tags: ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I was wondering what advice someone can give me on maximising the graph making module in MS Access. 
Recently, i was lucky to see a database made by a real expert and was astonished with the on screen graphs (of all types) which were embedded in forms allowing the users to have real time trend analysis-type information based on the underlying tables.

I wasn't aware that this functionality was available and so efficient in Access.

I would appreciate any feedback someone can give me on how to have access to this functionality (I imagine it involves installing some type of add-in) and put me on the right track on how to get up to speed in creating and effectively using graph design functionalities in my databases.

Thanks,
A

Answer (score 0):

If you open a table you will be able to change the `view` to `PivotChart` from the Access Ribbon. From there you only have to select a few items and you have a graph, chart etc.

If you want to embed this in a form, create a form with `Default View` property set to `Pivot Chart` and add it to your main form as a subform.